# Tranform Dataset With Two Dates In Different Cells into Series or Sequence (Google Sheet)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to transform dataset in google sheet that contains two dates in different cells into data series with single column date. Here is the ilustration:

Original Dataset:

| ID | Start Date | End Date | Name | Category | Subcategory |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10001 | 09/07/2021 | 11/07/2021 | Jona | A | A1 |
| 10002 | 10/07/2021 | 11/07/2021 | Adam | B | B1 |

Needed:

| ID | Date | Name | Category | Subcategory |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10001 | 09/07/2021 | Jona | A | A1 |
| 10001 | 10/07/2021 | Jona | A | A1 |
| 10001 | 11/07/2021 | Jona | A | A1 |
| 10002 | 10/07/2021 | Adam | B | B1 |
| 10002 | 11/07/2021 | Adam | B | B1 |

I need the second data structure to avoid using index and match to lookup record with multiple criteria that takes long process (over 3000 rows). Further, I need it so that I can apply date range filter in Google Data Studio that requires dates series.

All I have tried is to use **Sequence** function to populate dates between two given dates, but it only gives me series of dates without other cells data (I refer to [this method](https://www.sheetaki.com/auto-populate-dates-between-two-given-dates-in-google-sheets)).

Do you have any idea? I will appreciate your help. Thanks a lot!

**Update Question July 20, 2022:**

Is it possible to do the opposite? I mean transform data series into date range (transform the second table into the first table). Really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SEQUENCE` works well, but not with `ARRAYFORMULA`.

Instead, try `REPT`:

```
=arrayformula({A1\"Date"\D1:F1;split(query(flatten(array_constrain(if(split(rept(10;C2:C-B2:B+1);0)=1;A2:A&char(9999)&B2:B+transpose(row(A:A))-1&char(9999)&D2:D&char(9999)&E2:E&char(9999)&F2:F;);counta(B2:B);max(C2:C-B2:B)+1));"where Col1 is not null";0);char(9999))})
```

[image]

It also works for the anomaly where each row of start dates are the same as end dates, because of the `array_constrain`.

In the initial array `counta(B2:B)` limits the rows, `max(C2:C-B2:B)+1)` limits the columns. `+1` ensures that it still works when all start dates are the same as end dates on each row.

[image]

Comment: Great, it worked perfectly! I have been using the Flatten and Split functions to convert multi-column data into a single column, but using them to create dates series from data containing two date ranges is the next level of difficulty, but you've just come up with a great solution. Thank you very much!

Comment: For you who use semicolon separators, you may need to slightly modify the formula just like this: 

`=arrayformula({A1\"Date"\D1:F1; query(split(flatten(if(B2:B<>"";if(split(rept(10;C2:C-B2:B+1);0)=1;A2:A&char(9999)&B2:B+column(1:1)-1&char(9999)&D2:D&char(9999)&E2:E&char(9999)&F2:F;);));char(9999));"where Col1 is not null";0)})` 

Again, thanks a lot Aresvik!

Comment: You're welcome. Happy to help. I've just updated the solution to remove `if(B2:B<>""` and then set `Col2 is not null`. It's a little bit simpler.

Comment: Regarding your solution, it works fine until I found a case where several records contained the same start and end date. When the condition exists, the IDs are repeated until a month ahead. 

To give you an idea, please refer: [link](https://snipboard.io/aLc68W.jpg) 

I've tried to figure out, but it seems quite complicated to me. Please help me Aresvik.

Comment: Not sure what's going on but the issue seems to be the `+column(1:1)-1` for this condition. I have a temp fix using `array_constrain`. Solution updated.

Comment: I've updated the solution again. `+column(1:1)-1` has been replaced with `+transpose(row(A:A))-1` so you don't need as many columns as there are max days between any start and end date.

Comment: Hello Aresvik, is it possible to do the opposite? I mean transform data series into date range (table 2 to table 1 from my question). Really appreciate your help!

Comment: Try query:
=query({A:E};"select Col1,min(Col2),max(Col2),Col3,Col4,Col5 where Col1 is not null group by Col1,Col3,Col4,Col5 label min(Col2) 'Start Date', max(Col2) 'End Date'";1)

Comment: Thank you so much, Aresvik. It works! For you who want to order by date, simply put "order by min(Col2)" just before label:

=query(A:E;"select A, min(B), max(B), C, D, E where A is not null group by A, C, D, E order by min(B) label min(B) 'Start Date', max(B) 'End Date'";1)